# Alam not working on schedule time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating an android app in which user can add multiple babies, each baby have multiple dates on which alarm being called.
I am getting dates from **SQLite Database** After fetching dates, the alarm will be setting to those dates. I have set everything correctly, but alarm not working properly.

**Here is the code .**

```
List  babyDataList = new ArrayList<>();
List  listItems = new ArrayList<>();

Database db = new Database();

babyDataList = db.getAllBabies();
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calenderThird = Calendar.getInstance();

for(BabyModal b : babyDataList ){
 String name = b.getBabyName();
 String first = b.getFirstVac(); // FirstDate
 String sec = b.getSecVac(); //SecondDate

 String[] val1 = first.split("-");
  int dateSec = Integer.parseInt(val1[0]);
  int monthSec = Integer.parseInt(val1[1]);
  int yearSec = Integer.parseInt(val1[2]);
   calendar.set(
       yearSec, monthSec-1, dateSec, 8, 30, 30
   );
 setAlarm(calendar);

String[] val2 = sec.split("-");
   int dateThird = Integer.parseInt(val2[0]);
   int monthThird = Integer.parseInt(val2[1]);
   int yearThird = Integer.parseInt(val2[2]);
  calenderThird.set(
       yearThird, monthThird-1, dateThird, 8, 30, 30
  );
     setAlarm(calendarThird);

   listItems.add(b);
}
```

The Method for **setAlarm** is

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar cal){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            (int) cal.getTimeInMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am =
            (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}
```

**AlarmReceiver** class :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MyNewIntentService.class);
    context.startService(intent1);
  }
}
```

**MyNewIntentService** class:

```
    public class MyNewIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 3;

    public MyNewIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
      @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Vaccination Time");
        builder.setContentText(" ");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.health);
            builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        builder.setSound(alarmSound);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
        if(isScreenOn==false){
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"MyLock");
            wl.acquire(10000);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyCpuLock");

            wl_cpu.acquire(10000);
        }
       Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, BabiesList.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //to be able to launch your activity from the notification
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not gonna solve your problem whatever you have posted and wants to resolve; rather i would try to clear basics...

### What is `alarm manager`

It is `not the one` which system uses for `traditional alarms` for waking up the persons from sleep, rather it is the same concept... but for the `developers`; who wants to `wake up their piece of code at the specified time`...

### How to `wake up my code` then...

> Note below code is working across `4.0 to the latest android P`; `tested` on all

```
Calendar CalendarEvent = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
CalendarEvent.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Log.d("SCHEDULER : ", "CALENDAR SET TIME :"+CalendarEvent.getTime()+"\n");

Intent myintent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myintent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, CalendarEvent.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

### `What is this`...??

Here `HOUR_OF_DAY` is set to 14 meaning `2PM` in the `afternoon` as per your default timezone. On 2PM, it will start `MyService` and note it is `not necessary` that your application must remain in `foreground` or `background` or in `recents`...!! `IT WILL GET CALLED`...

### What the `permissions` are needed

only `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` if you wants... Note that `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />` is `not necessary` as it is intended for `traditional alarms`

### What are the `deadlines`...?

`Until next-boot` these alarms are `remembered` by the android systems..!! On the next boot all the alarms are `deleted` by android system... It means if you set the alarm on 20 jan 2018 and if device is rebooted on the day before or even the `timeinmillis` before... `android will forget it`

### How to remember it `across every boot`...?

Use a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `intent` for `receiver` with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` permission and re-set all the alarms `manually`... `again`... with the help of database `table`

### `It is not the answer of my question which i asked`....

`Yes, it is`. Implement this `concept` first in a `sample` new `project`. clear the concept with such a code which runs across the android platforms in the all cases you wants... And `then implement it in the way you wants` ... in the main projects.

Huuushhhh...

Comment: I have implemented the code on other project and I know the basics.
On new project the alarm works fine. But when I am doing it with database its not working

Comment: And You have mentioned it works fine before android P
What about after P devices